# Is there a way for a function to save a variable from one call to the next

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function on multiple html select elements that calls getPaymentAmount(this). When I select an option on the first select element and getPaymentAmount fires, is there a way to save the value for when I select an option on the next select element when the getPaymentAmount fires again?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="trim_list">
    <div class="w3-row w3-padding">
        <div class="w3-col m6">
            <label for="type_trim_1">Type of Trim for horse 1:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-col m6">
            <select id="type_trim_1" class="w3-input w3-border w3-border-black addCost" name="type_trim[]" onChange="getPaymentAmount(this);" required="">
                <option value="">Select Type of Trim</option>
                <option value="40:trim">Regular Trim</option>
                <option value="130:front">Front Shoes</option>
                <option value="190:all">All Four Shoes</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-row w3-padding">
        <div class="w3-col m6">
            <label for="type_trim_2">Type of Trim for horse 2:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-col m6">
            <select id="type_trim_2" class="w3-input w3-border w3-border-black addCost" name="type_trim[]" onChange="getPaymentAmount(this);" required="">
                <option value="">Select Type of Trim</option>
                <option value="40:trim">Regular Trim</option>
                <option value="130:front">Front Shoes</option>
                <option value="190:all">All Four Shoes</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-row w3-padding">
        <div class="w3-col m6">
            <label for="type_trim_3">Type of Trim for horse 3:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-col m6">
            <select id="type_trim_3" class="w3-input w3-border w3-border-black addCost" name="type_trim[]" onChange="getPaymentAmount(this);" required="">
                <option value="">Select Type of Trim</option>
                <option value="40:trim">Regular Trim</option>
                <option value="130:front">Front Shoes</option>
                <option value="190:all">All Four Shoes</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my javascript function:

```
function getPaymentAmount(e){
    let total = 0; // The total amount paid stored here
    let val = e.value; // the value of the select element. This value is of 40:trim OR 130:front OR 190:all
            
    let eleVal = val.split(':'); // Splitting the value to get the numeric value
    let price = parseInt(eleVal[0]); // Turning the string into a number
                
    // The alerts are for figuring out a way to try to make this work
    alert(price); // Alerts to 40 for first select element selection
    alert(typeof(price)); // Alerts to number
            
    // How can I save this price i.e. (40) for when the next select element is selected in order
    // to add the prices together?
            
    $('paid').value = total; // This is the input field to show the total price of the selected elements    
}
```

I have tried to call the function within itself, hoping it would save the first value. I believe that is recursive?? Didn't work. I have tried counting the amount of select elements (they are created dynamically). This method works if I only have a numeric value for my select elements. But I'm needing to pass along the string as well, Hence the value="40:trim" value="130:front" value="190:all". With the loop I keep getting a NaN error when I split the value.

Comment: You'd need to pass it to the function or make it a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `total` variable has function scope. It's only defined for the duration of the function, and it's redefined each time that function is invoked. You could define it globally, which would maintain its value across invocations, but that's generally not preferred if there are better options.

I took some liberties with your code below. My version recalculates the total each time by iterating over your `<select>` elements. It doesn't depend on maintaining a `total` value across invocations, and it doesn't rely on a global variable.

*NOTE: this is a pure JS solution. I suspect your original version relied on jQuery.*

```js
const selectors = [...document.querySelectorAll("select[name=type_trim]")];

function getPaymentAmount() {
  let total = 0;

  //iterate over the selectors and sum their values
  //(or use `reduce` if you don't like iterating)
  selectors.forEach(sel => {
    if (sel.value) {
      let numval = +sel.value.split(":")[0]; //"+" coerces to value instead of string
      total += numval;
    }
  })

  document.querySelector('#paid').value = total; // This is the input field to show the total price of the selected elements    
}
```

```html
<div id="trim_list">
  <div class="w3-row w3-padding">
    <div class="w3-col m6">
      <label for="type_trim_1">Type of Trim for horse 1:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col m6">
      <select id="type_trim_1" class="w3-input w3-border w3-border-black addCost" name="type_trim" onChange="getPaymentAmount();" required="">
        <option value="">Select Type of Trim</option>
        <option value="40:trim">Regular Trim</option>
        <option value="130:front">Front Shoes</option>
        <option value="190:all">All Four Shoes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-row w3-padding">
    <div class="w3-col m6">
      <label for="type_trim_2">Type of Trim for horse 2:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col m6">
      <select id="type_trim_2" class="w3-input w3-border w3-border-black addCost" name="type_trim" onChange="getPaymentAmount();" required="">
        <option value="">Select Type of Trim</option>
        <option value="40:trim">Regular Trim</option>
        <option value="130:front">Front Shoes</option>
        <option value="190:all">All Four Shoes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-row w3-padding">
    <div class="w3-col m6">
      <label for="type_trim_3">Type of Trim for horse 3:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col m6">
      <select id="type_trim_3" class="w3-input w3-border w3-border-black addCost" name="type_trim" onChange="getPaymentAmount();" required="">
        <option value="">Select Type of Trim</option>
        <option value="40:trim">Regular Trim</option>
        <option value="130:front">Front Shoes</option>
        <option value="190:all">All Four Shoes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <input id="paid">
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have been trying to do. Thank you. I'm not as versed in javascript as I am in PHP, and I appreciate the answer, but I'm going to try to wrap my head around what you posted. The selectors is an array of all the select elements on the page with the name type_trim. Then in the function you are iterating over all the select elements with the forEach(). Now what is kind of throwing me is you have sel => { }. This is considered an object?? What is the purpose of if? everything after that I understand. I was trying something similiar, it just wasn't working out. I kept getting.

Comment: an error saying that splice was not a function. Couldn't seem to get past that part but I did not put the .splice(':')[0] at the end.

Comment: ok, I get it. the sel => {} is the same as saying function(sel){ }.... Thanks Marc